# How can I write these functions to be independent of choice of type: Int vs Integer

Tags: haskell, types, integer

I'm working through [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net), and a lot of problems involve similar functions, for example calculating lists of primes. I know calculations with Integer are slower than Int so I'd like to write the functions to work with both, depending on the size of the numbers I'm working with.

```
module Primes
(
    isPrime
    ,prime 
    ,allPrimes
)
where

import Data.List

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
    | n == 0 = False
    | n == 1 = False
    | n < 0 = isPrime (-n)
    | n < 4 = True
    | n `mod` 2 == 0 = False
    | n `mod` 3 == 0 = False
    | any ( (==0) . mod n ) [5..h] = False
    | otherwise = True
    where
        h = ( ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral ) n


allPrimes :: [Int]
allPrimes = [ x | x<- [2..], isPrime x ]

prime :: Int -> Int
prime n = allPrimes !! (n-1)
```

I know this code isn't generally as optimal as it could be. I'm just interested in how to make the integer types more generic.

Comment: I posted a short code review of `isPrime` (with a focus on preserving the exact algorithm presented here) at http://hpaste.org/50988 (if you're interested).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Integral` it should allow support for both `Int` and `Integer`

Comment: Sounds good. I can't paste the actual code without losing all the formatting, but I replaced the signatures with: 

isPrime :: (Integral n) => n -> Bool
allPrimes :: (Integral n) => [n]
prime :: (Integral n, Integral m) => n -> m

and I get this error: "Primes.hs:29:24:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' against inferred type `n'
      `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `prime' at Primes.hs:28:19"

Comment: @Peter Hall the `(!!)` function takes an `Int` parameter.  prime should have type `Integral n => Int -> n`.

Answer (score 7):

A more general solution to this kind of problem, you could try getting your code to compile without the explicit type declarations. Haskell will assume the most general type possible and you can find out what it was by, for example, loading your file on GHCi and doing a `:t myFunctionName`